# Applying Outline Effect to Objects in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

---

I'm working on a Three.js project and trying to apply an outline effect to specific objects in my scene. I've included the necessary Three.js scripts for post-processing and outline effects

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three/examples/js/loaders/GLTFLoader.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.129.0/examples/js/postprocessing/EffectComposer.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.129.0/examples/js/postprocessing/RenderPass.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.129.0/examples/js/postprocessing/ShaderPass.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.129.0/examples/js/postprocessing/OutlinePass.js"></script>
```

Here's my code:

```js
// Load a 3D model
function loadModel(modelToLoad) {
  loader.load(
    modelToLoad,
    function (gltf) {
      modelDefault = gltf.scene;
      scene.add(modelDefault);
      applySelectionEffect(modelDefault);
      enableObjectMovement(modelDefault);
      animate();
    },
    undefined,
    function (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  );
}

function applyOutlineEffect(object) {
  
}

function clearOutlineEffect(object) {
  
}
```

Specifically, I need help with:

How to correctly set up the outline effect using EffectComposer, RenderPass, and OutlinePass.
How to apply the outline effect to a specific object in my scene when it's selected.
How to clear the outline effect when the object is deselected.
Any guidance or code examples on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!